# Create graph of distinct routes

Tags: graph, shortest-path, maze

**Problem** I have a binary image with traversable and blocked cells. On this map points of interest (POIs) are set. My goal is to create a graph from these POIs respecting obstacles (see images) which represents all possible and truly distinct paths. Two paths are truly distinct if they can not be joined into one path. E.g. if the outside of the building in picture 1 was accessible a path around the building could not be merged with one through the building.

[image: Floor plan example]
[image]

**Researched** I have looked at maze solvers and various shortest path finding algorithms (e.g. A*, Theta*, Phi*) and while they'd be useful for this problem they only search for a path between two points and don't consider already established routes.

**Best Guess** I am considering using Phi* to search for all possible routes and merge afterwards using magic (ideas?), but this will not give me truly distinct alternatives.

Can someone help?

P.S.: I'm using C++ and am not really eager to do this by myself, so if there is a library which already does this... :)

Answer (score 0):

I found (and decided to use) a parallel thinning algorithm (Zhan-Suen for now) to create an image skeleton. This effectively makes the assumption that the geometry shapes the common routes, which is fine I think.

By using the Rutovitz crossing number I can extract bifurcations and crossings from the resulting skeleton. Then I'll determine the shortest line of sight from my Points of Interest (using Bresenham's algorithm) to the extracted crossings to connect them to the graph.

I hope this will help someone along the road :)